# Fairly new to C# and am trying to make a sort of quiz game but can't find an or operator

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

(Written in C#, need "or" for different variations of "yes")

```
Console. WriteLine("Are you ready to begin?");

string response1 = Console. ReadLine();

if(response1 == "Yes")
{
    Console. WriteLine("Okay, first question...");
}
else if(response1 != "Yes")
{
    //loop until they say yes
}


Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: VS Code is an editor. You question has nothing to do with VS Code. It's a C# question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just ... use [or](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-or-operator-):

```
if (respnonse1 == "yes" || response1 == "y")
```

The next thing you can do is make a case insensitive test:

```
if (respnonse1.ToLower() == "yes" || response1.ToLower() == "y")
```

If you have more accepted variants you can put them in a collection. There are multiple ways to implement, this is a quick one using [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0):

```
if (new[] {"yes", "y", "accept", "ok"}.Contains(response1.ToLower()))
```